# Does K&R second edition explain typedefs for function pointers

Tags: c

Does K&R 2nd edition explain the usage of typedefs to make declaration and use of function pointers easier? I lost my copy and can't recollect of it does or it does not.

Thanks.

Comment: K&R was a good book when C first came out and even when ANSI standardised it. It is _not_ a good book for the modern language (which has changed massively since 1990) and you would be better off looking elsewhere. I have long since tossed mine out (though, strangely enough, I still have the Lions commentary book on UNIX).

Comment: @paxdiablo K&R2 is a solid introductory text IMHO (of course there are other options, which it would be offtopic to mention!)

Comment: Briefly, on page 120.

Comment: @paxdiablo: The language hasn't changed so much since 1990 that K&R2 is no longer a good book. A beginner could do worse than studying K&R2 and then learning about the changes in C99 and C11 (which some compilers don't even support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is explained in section 6.7, "Typedefs".